# Easiest way to improve garage floor

Tags: flooring, garage, product-recommendation

My garage's floor is concrete. Its age is showing, so it several small holes and it is hard to keep clean.

I'm trying to find the best option to improve it without a major expense. One option is to just clean and paint. I have also looked into epoxy coating, but it looks like preparation could be a really painful job.

So I'm wondering is there is something in between: more solid than paint, but easier to apply than the common epoxys I find at the store.

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: something like [this](https://allgaragefloors.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/dusting-concrete-garage-floor.jpg).

Comment: I meant a picture of your floor's specific damage issues. If you're not looking to do it right then slap some paint down and call it a day. If this is a shopping question then it's off-topic but you could try a 1-part epoxy paint like this https://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-PREMIUM-1-gal-Slate-Gray-Self-Priming-1-Part-Epoxy-Satin-Interior-Exterior-Concrete-and-Garage-Floor-Paint-90201/308800274

Comment: scrub it with dishwater detergent, let it soak 1 hour, then hose the heck out of it then epoxy; not that bad. The risk w/epoxy is it coming up in a few years. Keep extra and patch it when that happens. Unlike a clean and smooth ceiling, a patched dirty garage floor typically isn't noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a lot of smaller cracks, you could use a concrete crack filler with a caulking gun or vinyl concrete patching compound with a putty knife.  Lowe's has a great [step-by-step](https://www.lowes.com/n/how-to/simple-concrete-repairs) guide on how to do this.

If you want to completely redo your sealing, acrylic is a good alternative to epoxy and it is easier to use and better for wetter climates.  [This guide from The Spruce](https://www.thespruce.com/sealing-concrete-driveway-2132035) goes over the different types of sealers and how to apply them.